# How to doing ssrs query with date and time parameters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm just new in SSRS reporting service and need help, I can get my data in sql server with this code:

```
SELECT [name],[Time],[valueX],[valueY] FROM [mybase].[my].[mytable] where Time between '2020-02-21 23:00:00.001' and '2020-02-22 06:59:59.999' order by Time
```

The time variable it set manually, so it no problem.
the problem starts when I try that query to my SSRS-reporting.

How to get make date start + time start like '2020-02-21 23:00:00.001' and date end + time end like '2020-02-22 06:59:59.999'.

[image: this is parameter I try to input]

[image: and this is result i try to get in my ssrs report]

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here. Perhaps you're asking how to parametrise a SSRS report?

Comment: @Larnu that what i mean, i try to make parameters date start with time start and date end with time end. so the output data from '2020-02-21 23:00:00.001' until '2020-02-22 06:59:59.999'. its different day.

Comment: What's a different day? You aren't making any sense here.

Comment: @Larnu my first day param is 21 februari 2020 11PM, and second day param is 22 februari 2020 7AM . is it not different day??

Comment: Yes... and that's what you have in your query... `between '2020-02-21 23:00:00.001' and '2020-02-22 06:59:59.999'` Again, what's the problem here? What are you asking?

Comment: my problem i don't know how to write correctly query in ssrs report, because the result always empty, that query i write on top is my query on sql server.

Comment: Show us the query in SSRS. The parametrised one.

Comment: this is my query in SSRS

SELECT        Time, X, Y, sensorname
FROM            ANM1
WHERE        (Time >= @StartDate) AND (Time <= @EndDate) AND (DATEPART(HOUR, Time) >= @StartHour) AND (DATEPART(HOUR, Time) <= @EndHour)
ORDER BY Time DESC

Comment: That should be in your question, not the comments.

Comment: @Larnu that's my bad, thanks a lot for your advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is your parametrisation. Let's take your query:

```sql
SELECT [time],
       X,
       Y,
       sensorname
FROM ANM1
WHERE ([time] >= @StartDate)
  AND ([time] <= @EndDate)
  AND (DATEPART(HOUR, [time]) >= @StartHour)
  AND (DATEPART(HOUR, [time]) <= @EndHour)
ORDER BY [time] DESC;
```

You have 2 parts here, firstly `([time] >= @StartDate) AND ([time] <= @EndDate)` and then   `AND (DATEPART(HOUR, [time]) >= @StartHour) AND (DATEPART(HOUR, [time]) <= @EndHour)`. The first part is fine, you want rows where `[time]` is on or after `20200221` and `[time]` is on or before `20200222`.

The problem, however, is the latter part, where you want rows where the hour of `[time]` is greater than or equal to `23` and the hour part of `[time]` is less than or equal to `6`. I can assure you, there are no numbers that are greater than 23 and less than 6.

SSRS has no native Date **and** time data type, so we're going to need to concatenate the 2 values and use some messy conversions:

```
SELECT [time],
       X,
       Y,
       sensorname
FROM ANM1
WHERE [time] >= CONVERT(datetime2(3),CONCAT(CONVERT(varchar(10),@StartDate,23),'T',CONVERT(varchar(12),@StartHour,114)),126)
  AND [time] <= CONVERT(datetime2(3),CONCAT(CONVERT(varchar(10),@EndDate,23),'T',CONVERT(varchar(12),@EndHour,114)),126);
```

Comment: i try your query and it's showing an error message Failed to convert parameter value from a string to a DateTime, the concat function requires 2 argument(s). i'm using sql server-2008

Comment: The conversion is working fine for me, @herdinjaya . That suggests your passing an invalid time. Certainly `CONCAT` has 3 parameters in that query, suggesting you've changed the query. [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0294922ba7aec2ce087250edde2f1149) If you change the query, and then no, it's not going to work as I expect.

Comment: Just noticed *"i'm using sql server-2008*...`CONCAT` was introduced in SQL Server 2012, @herdinjaya . Telling people you are using **completely unsupported**software is *very* important as we'll assume otherwise that you have a supported version. I *strongly* suggest you look at upgrade paths, as 2008 has been usupported for a year now. You'll have to change `CONCAT` to the old `+` operator.

Comment: then how suppose i write my query if 'CONCAT' doesn't work in my 2008 ??

Comment: As I said, @herdinjaya *"You'll have to change CONCAT to the old + operator."*

Comment: yes, it's really help me @Larnu.  I really appreciate the help. thanks a lot.